# MySQL puts date as 0000-00-00 when inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
$date = new DateTime();

$date->modify('+21 day');

$newDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$sql = "UPDATE `teams` SET `next` = 'strtotime($newDate)' WHERE `id` = 1";
```

This is my code, when it updates in my database it stores the update date as 0000-00-00.

Comment: strtotime is not mathicng DB format. Change date formate also before insert.

Comment: (and you're wide open to SQL injection)

Comment: you can use as date('Y-m-d' ,strtotime($newDate))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the string  `strtotime($newDate)` as the value.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `teams` SET `next` = '$newDate' WHERE `id` = 1";
```

This will simply write your `Y-m-d` formatted value into the `next` column.

See for yourself: https://3v4l.org/lQuXl

You are feeding an invalid value to a date column, MySQL is falling back to `0000-00-00` by default.